# Vimeo video embeds doesnt seem to work with ACF

Tags: embed, video-player, vimeo

I was trying to embed a vimeo link **into a site using ACF custom fields** and I am not getting anything in the front end but just a blank space as shown below.

[image]

I tried multiple approaches including a vimeo iframe as well as just pasting the link but nothing seems to work.

The embed code is given below

```
<h3>Watch a Video</h3>
<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/75791532?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="500" height="375" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
```

I checked multiple sites and all of them say I should be able to embed using the iframe or just the link, so I am not sure whats happening here.

Comment: Please add some more info about the setup. Have you used the [oEmbed field](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/oembed/)? Show us the part of the template where you display the field and so one...

Comment: Have you already tried the [Advanced Custom Fields Support Forums](http://support.advancedcustomfields.com/)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the custom field contains just the URL you can achieve this using [wp_oembed_get](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_oembed_get)

```
$video_url = 'https://vimeo.com/75791532';
$video = wp_oembed_get( $video_url );
echo $video;
```

If the custom field contains other content as well something like this should work.

```
$content = '<p>Check out hte latest vid!</p>
     https://vimeo.com/75791532';

$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
echo $content;
```

[the_content](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) filter automatically applies the oembed filter.

Comment: Sorry but it contains content too and not just the URL.

Comment: I've edited my answer.